# Django-south ValueError during a datamigration

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-south, data-migration

I'm making some updates on system built with Django, and now i'm having some trouble with a south datamigration.

I have a model Cargo, which has a Foreign Key to auth.User, and now i want to add a Foreign Key to another model(Company), that is related to the auth.User.

```
class Cargo(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        'accounts.Company',
        related_name='cargo_company',
        verbose_name='empresa',
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        related_name='cargo_customer',
        verbose_name='embarcador',
        limit_choices_to={'groups__name': 'customer'},
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
```

I also have a UserProfile model, which relates to auth.User and Company, like below:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company, 
        verbose_name='Empresa', 
        null=True
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User')
```

I created and ran a schemamigration to add the company field to Cargo, and then i created a datamigration, so that i could fill the company field of all my cargos. What i came up with was this:

```
class Migration(DataMigration):

def forwards(self, orm):
    try:
        from cargobr.apps.accounts.models import UserProfile
    except ImportError:
        return

    for cargo in orm['cargo.Cargo'].objects.all():
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=cargo.customer)
        cargo.company = profile.company
        cargo.save()
```

But when i try to run it, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "<Company: Thiago Rodrigues>": "Cargo.company" must be a "Company" instance.
```

But as you can see in the models above, both fields are of the same kind... Can anyone give me a light with this? I'm on Django 1.3.1 and South 0.7.3

**EDIT:** As asked below, the `UserProfile` and `Company` models are in an `accounts` module, and `Cargo` is in a `cargo`. So, putting it short, i have `accounts.UserProfile`, `accounts.Company` and `cargo.Cargo`

Comment: What module is `UserProfile` in? It seems you are referencing `Company` directly from there, but in `Cargo` you use `'accounts.Company'`. Do you have two classes with the same name?

Comment: Both `UserProfile` and `Company` are in the `accounts` app, and `Cargo` is in the `cargo` app, so that`s why i`m referencing `Company` directly in `UserProfile`, and not in `Cargo`

Comment: It may be due to your direct import of `UserProfile`. According to the [South tutorial on datamigrations](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html), one method to access models from different apps is using `orm['someapp.SomeModel']`, so in your case you could do `orm['accounts.UserProfile']` instead of `from cargobr ...`. This mechanism ensures that the instances of the models are the same ones as when the data migration was created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a mismatch between the model versions that you are using, because you imported directly:

```
from cargobr.apps.accounts.models import UserProfile
```

Instead, try referencing that model using `orm` in your migration.

```
class Migration(DataMigration):

def forwards(self, orm):
    for cargo in orm['cargo.Cargo'].objects.all():
        profile = orm['accounts.UserProfile'].objects.get(user=cargo.customer)
        cargo.company = profile.company
        cargo.save()
```

Comment: Thanks! I only had to do one extra thing for this to work out: I had to re-create the datamigration, this time with the `--freeze accounts` param, to include this model in the migration. Then it worked perfectly!

Comment: Cheers, already been using it for quite some time, but just recently i started to ask questions.. Hopefully i'll be able to help other people in the future